# Optimize JSON insertion to SQLite (insert ... on duplicate key ignore)

Tags: java, parsing, android, json, sqlite

In current task, I'm refactoring the code of converting JSON file into SQLite database on Android device. Code compliant with Java 6.

As a benchmark, grabbing the code from remote server takes `~1 second`, but parsing it and 
saving to database takes `up to 1 minute`

In file there is approximately 100 branches, where is has 2 services, which is like 300 queries. Each query takes up to `100 ms`

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(coupons);
JSONArray branches = response.getJSONArray("branches");
String lastTimestamp = "";
for(int i = 0; i < branches.length(); i++){
    JSONObject branch = branches.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject b = branch.getJSONObject("Branch");
    // add Branch
    lastTimestamp = b.getString("timestamp");
    addBranch(
            b.getInt("id"),
            b.getString("longitude"),
            b.getString("latitude"),
            b.getString("heading"),
            b.getString("address"),
            b.getString("opening_hours"),
            b.getString("region"),
            b.getString("country"),
            b.getString("phone"),
            b.getString("type"),
            lastTimestamp
            );

            // add Services
    JSONArray services = branch.getJSONArray("Service");
    for(int o = 0; o < services.length(); o++){
        JSONObject s = services.getJSONObject(o);
        addService(
            s.getInt("id"),
            s.getInt("branch_id"),
            s.getString("name")
            );
    }
    // end loop adding branches & services
}
```

where methods used to insert to database are:

```
private long addBranch(
        int remote_id,
        String longitude,
        String latitude,
        String heading,
        String address,
        String opening_hours,
        String region,
        String country,
        String phone,
        String type,
        String timestamp
        ){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID, remote_id);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_HEADING, heading);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_OPENING_HOURS, opening_hours);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_REGION, region);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_COUNTRY, country);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_TYPE, type);
    long insertId = getDatabase().insertWithOnConflict(BranchSQL.TABLE_BRANCHES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    return insertId;
}

private long addService(int remote_id, int branch_id, String name){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_REMOTE_ID, remote_id);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_BRANCH_ID, branch_id);
    values.put(BranchSQL.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    long insertId = getDatabase().insertWithOnConflict(BranchSQL.TABLE_SERVICES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    return insertId ;
}
```

code creating structure of tables:

```
private static final String BRANCHES_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_BRANCHES
        + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_REMOTE_ID + " integer unique, "
        + COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_HEADING + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_ADDRESS + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_OPENING_HOURS + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_REGION + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_COUNTRY + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_PHONE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TYPE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " text null);";

private static final String SERVICES_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_SERVICES
        + "( " + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_REMOTE_ID + " integer unique, "
        + COLUMN_BRANCH_ID + " integer, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null );";
```

*Note that almost all fields in BRANCH type are text, to not slowing down inserting rows by parsing `Integer, Double, Date, ...` values*

This is probably the simplest way to do it. But it looks like it is also the most in-effective way.

Second way, I can think about, is using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse whole branch&services object to Java Object, but this looks to me not very memory/cpu usage friendly.

Can I please kindly ask for your optimizing tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to do a [bulk insert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_insert), which is notoriously slow on many databases if you're not careful. Indeed, each call to `insertWithOnConflict()` creates a new transaction, then inserts, then closes the transaction. Instead, use [beginTransaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) and [endTransaction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#endTransaction()) to have only a single transaction (the doc explains how to use them with a try/catch block).

Up to API 16, it was possible to use `DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper`, but this is now deprecated. [This blog post](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/) uses `DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper`, which is not a good idea anymore. But it has other interesting performance tweaks you could try out:

- Don’t bind empty columns to avoid producing useless SQL. This will lead to a speedup if you often have empty columns. (half of the author columns are empty and he reports a 30% speedup).
- Disable thread locking temporarily: for various reasons, this is **very dangerous**, and should only be attempted if you know the implications, can prove it won't do any harm, and *really* need the ~30% speedup reported by the author.

Of course, there are probably other optimisations, like trying to do this in a background thread, doing this only once when the user doesn't mind. If the speedups provided by the above solutions really don't help, displaying a progress bar can make your app feel like it's doing something important, which will be less frustrating for the user.

Comment: Oh gosh, sorry, see code posted under my question. I've took your suggestions and now it takes under 5 seconds whatever :)) Thanks

Comment: InsertHelper is deprecated now see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344928/1665247)

Comment: Thanks @dvrm, I updated my answer. Feel free to improve it too.